# Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$. Describe the set of all vectors in $F^{m}$ orthogonal to $Im A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $A$ be a real $m\times n$ matrix. 
Describe the set of all vectors in $\mathbb F^{m}$ orthogonal to $Im A$.

source: *Linear Algebra Done Wrong by Gilbert Strang.*

I'm having trouble understanding this question. Does a real $m\times n$ matrix imply it's going from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $\mathbb R^{m}$ or it just has real entries? How would we find the set of orthogonal vectors to $Im A$.

Comment: _Real_ $m\times n$ _matrix A_ is commonly denoted by: $$A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)\;\lor\;A\in M_{mn}(\mathbb R).$$

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I'm concerned about is whether it can represent a linear transformation from $F^{n}$ to $F^{m}$?

Comment: Yes, it can, where $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the system $$A^Tx = 0$$

The solution describes the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ that are orthogonal to the columns of $A$.

The nullspace of $A^T$ is orthogonal to the $Ran A$.